# To find all functions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ we have that $x-y \in \mathbb Q \implies f(x) - f(y) \in \mathbb Q$.

I noticed that $x-y \in \mathbb Q \implies f^n(x) - f^n(y) \in \mathbb Q$ ($f^2(x) = f(f(x))$ and not $f(x) \cdot f(x)$).

I also tried to partition $\mathbb R = A \cup B$ where $A = \{x, f(x) \in \mathbb Q\}$ and $B = \{x, f(x) \in \mathbb R-\mathbb Q\}$ and to analyze: when $f(0)$ is rational and when it isn't.

If $0 \in B$ then $\mathbb Q \in B$. My problem is to verify $f$ of irrational numbers. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: How about all $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ plus a constant?

Comment: the problem is the domain the relation $x-y \in \mathbb Q$ works for irrationals too. If the domain were $\mathbb Q$ you would be correct.

Comment: $f(x)=ax+r$ where $a$ is rational and $r$ real is good and so are $f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ and $f(x)=\lceil{x}\rceil$.

Comment: I did not think of the floor function. Maybe the answer is as general as alexis pointed out. Maybe all functions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ and a few more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a group theoretic approach. Let $S$ be the set of functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $x-y \in \mathbb{Q} \implies f(x) - f(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$. $S$ is an abelian group under pointwise addition. Let $A$ be the set of functions (not neccesarily group homomorphisms) $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is the quotient group. $A$ is also an abelian group under pointwise addition.

There is a function $F : S \to A$ defined by $F(f)([x]) = [f(x)]$. $F$ is a group homomorphism, and we will prove that $F$ is surjective. By the axiom of choice, let $\iota : \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a section of the canonical projection $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. This gives a map $I := \varphi \mapsto \iota \circ \varphi \circ \pi : A \to S$, which is a section of $F$ since
$$F(I(\varphi)) \circ \pi = \pi \circ I(\varphi) = \pi \circ \iota \circ \varphi \circ \pi = \varphi \circ \pi$$
and $\pi$ is surjective. By the first isomorphism theorem, there exists a bijection $A \times \ker F \to S$, so we should seek to understand $\ker F$.

If $f \in \ker F$, we have that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $[f(x)] = F(f)([x]) = [0] = \mathbb{Q}$, so $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$. Conversely, if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$, then $f \in \ker F$ (technically, it's the corestriction of $f$ that's in the kernel). We conclude that $\ker F$ is (in bijection with) the set of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$.

This makes $\ker F$ an injective abelian group, so $S \cong \ker F \times A$ as abelian groups. The isomorphism is given by $f \mapsto (\ell(f), F(f)) : S \to \ker F \times A$ where $\ell : S \to \ker F$ is a homomorphic section of the inclusion $\ker F \to S$. However, I don't know how to pick $\ell$ without some kind of choice (or well-ordering, etc.). In any case, we can tell that $$\lvert{S}\rvert = \lvert \ker F \rvert \times \lvert A \rvert = \aleph_0^{\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert} \cdot \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert^{\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert} = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert^{\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert} = 2^{\lvert\mathbb{R}\rvert},$$
so there are many such functions.

Comment: nice one, so it is much greater than the size of the set of functions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb Q$, right? I'm a noob in group theory but my guess is that the size of that set would be the size of $\mathbb R$ since this is the size of set of real sequences and $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same size. It is weird because this problem is on a list a professor gave me but I believe you.

Comment: I haven't accepted your answer yet because a tiny part of me wants to believe that it is possible to find all the "continuum plus 1" solutions

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but the other one exposed all the solutions.

Comment: I don't mean to disparage the other answer because it's correct, but I just want to point out that it only rephrases the problem and does not give any kind of classification. Indeed saying $\pi(f(x)) = \pi(f(y))$ is exactly the same thing as saying $f(x) - f(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$. So it's certainly valid to rephrase the problem this way (which is basically what I did in the first sentence of the second paragraph of my answer), but gives no new information about which functions satisfy this property.

Comment: Anyway, $\lvert S \rvert$ in this case is the same as the number of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$. It is potentially much larger than "continuum plus 1", in the sense that there may be many cardinalities strictly between $\lvert R \rvert$ and $\lvert S \rvert$!

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary function

$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

Now let's consider the equivalence relation

$$x\sim y \ \Leftrightarrow x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Now, you want that, $\forall x, \ y\in\mathbb{R} \ \mid x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)-f(y)\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Let's take

$$\pi:f(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow f(\mathbb{R})/\sim$$

Now it's easy.

Let

$$X=\lbrace f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\mid \pi(f(x)) = \pi(f(y)), \ \forall x, \ y \ such \ that \ x-y\in\mathbb{Q}\rbrace$$

Now you can see it better.